# Using string.pop_back() and string.back()

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm trying to use the `string` member functions `back()` and `pop_back()`, but I think my compiler doesn't recognize them as members.  However, when I use the option `-std=c++0x`, the compiler stops complaining only about `back()`, but still complains about `pop_back()`.  Here are the code and compiler errors:

Test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <string>  // back(), pop_back()                             

int main()
{
  std::string str ("Optimist!");

  std::cout << str.back() << "\n";
  str.pop_back();

  std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

g++ Test.cpp:

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:8:20: error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘back’
Test.cpp:9:7: error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘pop_back’
```

g++ -std=c++0x Test.cpp:

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:9:7: error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘pop_back’k’
```

How can I use these functions with g++?

EDIT:  Using g++ 4.6.3

Comment: Solve it by upgrading your compiler. :) GCC 4.8.1 [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/845ab2f270c1a6a1), it seems you are just using an older version which does not yet support those functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `std::basic_string::pop_back()` and `std::basic_string::back()` were [added to C++11.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) Without explicitly using the C++11 standard with `-std=c++11`, you won't be able to use these functions at all.

The current version of GCC is 4.8.2. Some earlier versions may not have one or both of these functions implemented. You should upgrade to 4.8.2 if you need them.

Comment: Thanks, Would you have a good link on how to do this on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: That's not quite correct. `--std=c++0x` is sufficient for ***some*** C++11 features and well worth a try as evidenced by the existence of `back()` in GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: @David [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal) might work for you...

Comment: @David Either upgrade Ubuntu, or install a local version of gcc (to avoid overwriting your system's compiler.) You're going to have to live with the fact that on certain linux distros, newer versions of gcc are not upstream.

Comment: @DanielFrey:  Well, I suppose that's true enough, although I recall that GCC recommends not using `std=c++0x` as it's deprecated.

Comment: @David:  here you go, I just had to do this today:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal

Comment: @JohnDibling I don't meant to recommend to use `-std=c++0x` when `-std=c++11` is available, just for older versions of GCC where `-std=c++11` doesn't even exist it's worth a try.

Comment: @JohnDibling Thanks for that, I just executed those commands given in the first answer but it still shows I'm using g++ 4.6.3, although gcc is now 4.8.1 so I'm still getting the same errors as above.  g++ -std=c++11 isn't recognized either. Any ideas?

Comment: @David The new version is called as `g++-4.8`, not `g++`. It doesn't replace the system's default compiler, it is just an additional compiler to use.

Comment: @JohnDibling @DanielFrey I just tried compiling using `g++-4.8` and it isn't being recognized.  I only ran those four commands I mentioned on the link, is there something more I need to do?  `-std=c++11` isn't recognized either.  Thanks again.

Comment: @David You need to be more specific, we can't read your mind. What exact commands have you tried and what is the error message you see? What does `g++-4.8 -std=c++11 source.cc` yield? Also: You might be better off asking on `askubuntu.com` than here if it is about installing GCC. Final note: Have you also tried `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8`? (Note: `g++-4.8`, not just `gcc-4.8`)?